# AngularJS filter orderBy, ordering one variable by another

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter, angularjs-orderby

I have a table that is made by ngRepeat from variable *first*. By filter, instead of *first.id_second* it writes out *second.name*, and it works great. Now I'm trying to sort the column *first.id_second* and I want it to be sorted not by *first.id_second*, but by *second.name*. This is my structure:

```
var first = [{ 
    "id": 0,
    "id_second": "111"
},{
    "id": 1,
    "id_second": "222"
}]

var second = [{
    "id_second": "111",
    "name": "name1"
},{
    "id_second": "222",
    "name": "name2"
}]
```

Usually, in my html I would have

```
ng-click="order('col_name')"
```

And in controller

```
$scope.order = function(predicate) {
    $scope.predicate = predicate;
    $scope.reverse = ($scope.predicate === predicate) ? !$scope.reverse : false;
    $scope.first = orderBy($scope.first, predicate, $scope.reverse);
 };

var orderBy = $filter('orderBy');
```

I don't know how to filter by a property that is from another variable. I suppose I should write a custom filter, but so far wasn't succesfull in it.

Any ideas? Thanx.

Comment: Just a suggestion, why not use lo-dash, with [_.sortBy](https://lodash.com/docs/3.10.1#sortBy) instead of angular `$filter` service - it has more flexibility ?

Comment: I am not fond of using additional libraries for just one "small" thing I need, especially if that means rewriting much of the code this project already has.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that there is no way to do this simple, so in the end I wrote a custom orderBy function in which I implemented quicksort.

```
// arranging data from second to get to the data easier
var secondKeyVal = {};
for (var i = 0; i < $scope.second.length; i++) {
    secondKeyVal[$scope.second[i].id_second] = $scope.second[i].naziv;
}

// function that is called from html
$scope.orderByCustom = function(predicate) {
    $scope.predicate = predicate;
    $scope.reverse = ($scope.predicate === predicate) ? !$scope.reverse : false;
    $scope.orderByCustomSort();
};

$scope.orderByCustomSort= function() {
    var sorted = quickSort($scope.first);
    $scope.first = sorted;
};

function quickSort(a) {
    if (a.length <= 1) return a;
    var left=[], right=[], pivot=secondKeyVal[a[0].id_second];
    for (var i = 1; i < a.length; i++) {
        secondKeyVal[a[i].id_second] <= pivot ? left.push(a[i]) : right.push(a[i]);
    }

    return quickSort(left).concat(a[0], quickSort(right));
}
```

Ofcourse, if anyone manages to pull this out without using additional libraries that would make me have to change html filters and orderBy I already use, it would be most welcome :)